# What is the signal of selecting an item in QListView?

Tags: python, pyqt4, selection, signals-slots, qlistview

I use

```
QObject.connect(self.image_list, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked(QModelIndex)'), self.on_row_changed)
```

initially, but I find that when I press the right button, `on_row_changed` will be called even though the item is grey(not the focus). Which signal should I connect?

I search through the documentation for qt4.8, and the signals `activated (const QModelIndex &index )`, `void indexesMoved (const QModelIndexList &indexes)` do not work.

So, when I try to do some action based on the focus item, which signal should I use that when I move the single-selection item using mouse or up/down arrow, a call-back will be invoked correctly?

Comment: you can check whether the QModelIndex is valid in on_row_changed

Comment: Wait, what is this? C++ or Python?

Comment: That's true, but when I change focus with arrow keys, it doesn't trigger.

Comment: You should select the `selectionChanged` signal i guess.

Comment: @Lawrence. `QListView.selectionChanged` is a protected method, not a signal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a `QListView`, you should connect to one of the [signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#signals) of its [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). To get changes to the current item as well as the selection, do:

```
    self.image_list.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.on_row_changed)
    ...

    def on_row_changed(self, current, previous):
        print('Row %d selected' % current.row())
```

Comment: Yes it works. And if I do not change the focus item, it won't trigger. That means `current` is always different from `previous`, and that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Strange, the first line crashes Python for me.

Comment: Turns out I need to keep a reference to the selection model, i.e. `self.z = self.myListView.selectionModel()` `self.z.currentChanged.connect(self.on_row_changed)`.